# C++ dynamic array size definition

Tags: c++

I am used to java and php and now I need to write some c++ code. I got difficulties to create a BYTE-array with dynamic size. How to achieve this?

```
int byteSize = shm.getMemorySize();
BYTE byte[44]; // replace 44 by byteSize
```

Comment: GCC supports writing `BYTE byte[byteSize];`

Comment: Depends. What is `BYTE`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `std::vector` unless you have very specific reason to use arrays. Normally, in the similar context where you were using arrays in other languages in C++ the default choice should be `std::vector`.

Comment: Last assumption is shared on only dynamic arrays, non the fixed size ones. For fixed size he can use std::array

Comment: He can, but it's rarely worth the effort, and pretty much never if you're new.

Comment: And the size?? You should mention `resize()` perhaps.

Comment: He can look up how to use it.

Answer (score 6):

Never use a naked pointer or it is open door for bugs and memory leaks, instead, here some alternatives :

```
int len = something;
std::vector<char> buffer(len,0);
```

or c++11 smart pointer

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer{ new char[len] };
```

or c++14 with make_unique

```
auto buffen = std::make_unique<char[]>(len);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a vector, unless you absolutely need to handle memory yourself.  Also, this is more of a preference thing, but I prefer to use uint8_t instead of BYTE.  Its a bit more compliant as it doesn't depend on GCC.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
...
std::vector<uint8_t> foo;
```

or

```
#include <cstdint>
...
uint8_t* data;
data = new uint8_t[10];
...
delete[] data;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the STL standard container class **`std::vector`** to have a dynamic resizable array:

```
#include <vector> // For std::vector
....

int byteSize = shm.getMemorySize();

// Create a vector of 'byteSize' bytes.
std::vector<BYTE> bytes(byteSize);
```

You can access vector elements using the usual `[]` syntax (e.g. `bytes[0]`, `bytes[1]`, ...`bytes[i]`).

`vector`'s destructor will *automatically* release the memory allocated by the vector, so you don't have to pay attention to freeing memory.

You can use vector's `push_back()` method to add items at the end of the vector (with automatic resizing). 
You can use vector's `clear()` method to empty it.
And vector's `size()` method returns the current number of items in the vector.

If you want to learn more about `std::vector`, you can watch [this great introductory video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-/C9-Lectures-Introduction-to-STL-with-Stephan-T-Lavavej) by Stephan T. Lavavej.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to use dynamic memory allocation with `new`

```
BYTE* data = new BYTE[byteSize];
data[0] = 0;
delete [] data;
```

However this approach in the hands of a beginner can lead to [memory corruptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption), crashes, [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), and all sorts of behaviors that are hard to find and fix.

A better way is to use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) that is almost safe against the problems the first approach has:

```
std::vector<BYTE> data;
data.resize(byteSize);
data[0] = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the dynamic array as follows:

```
int byteSize = shm.getMemorySize();
BYTE* byte = new BYTE[byteSize];
//Use the byte
delete [] byte;
```

Comment: Without context, nobody can rightfully say this is the wrong solution. But is only has a small niche left...

Comment: Without context, you certainly should not present it categorically as the correct solution. That is the far more important way of looking at this.

Comment: @tmp: The term "dynamic array" means that the array can be resized, elements removed, etc.  How does recommending new[] and delete[] accomplish this?  It can't do it -- you have to write all sorts of code to do the basics of what a dynamic array should be able to accomplish.  So no, the real answer is to use a container such as std::vector, which has all of tools needed to manipulate a dynamic array properly.