# Dynamically allocating memory

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and programming in general so i apologize if this is a trivial question.I am trying to initialize 2 arrays of size [600][600] and type str but my program keeps crashing.I think this is because these 2 arrays exceed the memory limits of the stack.Also,N is given by user so i am not quite sure if i can use new here because it is not a constant expression.

My code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct str {
int x;
int y;
int z;
};
int main(){
cin>>N;
str  Array1[N][N]; //N can be up to 200
str  Array2[N][N];
};
```

How could i initialize them in heap?I know that for a 1-D array i can use a vector but i don't know if this can somehow be applied to a 2-D array.

Comment: search for aggregate initialization

Comment: Yes, it most likely is because these two arrays exceed the size of your stack. What exactly do you mean by "How could I initialize them in memory"? They already are being placed "in memory". It's just that they are much larger than the space available in that place "in memory" where you're trying to put them, which is most likely why the program is blowing up…

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ dynamic array size definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22719332/c-dynamic-array-size-definition)

Comment: The code won't even compile, because `N` is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How 2-or-more-dimensional arrays work in C++

A 1D array is simple to implement and dereference. Assuming the array name is `arr`, it only requires one dereference to get access to an element.

Arrays with 2 or more dimensions, whether dynamic or stack-based, require more steps to create and access. To draw an analogy between a matrix and this, if `arr` is a 2D array and you want access to a specific element, let's say `arr[row][col]`, there are actually 2 dereferences in this step. The first one, `arr[row]`, gives you access to the `row`-th row of `col` elements. The second and final one, `arr[row][col]` reaches the exact element that you need.

Because `arr[row][col]` requires 2 dereferences for one to gain access, `arr` is no longer a pointer, but a *pointer to pointer*. With regards to the above, the first dereference gives you a pointer to a specific row (a 1D array), while the second dereference gives the actual element.

Thus, dynamic 2D arrays require you to have a pointer to pointer.

### To allocate a dynamic 2D array with size given at runtime

First, you need to create an array of pointers to pointers to your data type of choice. Since yours is `string`, one way of doing it is:

```cpp
std::cin >> N;
std::string **matrix = new string*[N];
```

You have allocated an array of row pointers. The final step is to loop through all the elements and allocate the columns themselves:

```cpp
for (int index = 0; index < N; ++index) {
    matrix[index] = new string[N];
}
```

Now you can dereference it just like you would a normal 2D grid:

```cpp
// assuming you have stored data in the grid
for (int row = 0; row < N; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < N; ++col) {
        std::cout << matrix[row][col] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

One thing to note: dynamic arrays are more computationally-expensive than their regular, stack-based counterparts. If possible, opt to use STL containers instead, like `std::vector`.

**Edit:** To free the matrix, you go "backwards":

```cpp
// free all the columns
for (int col = 0; col < N; ++col) {
    delete [] matrix[col];
}

// free the list of rows
delete [] matrix;
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you can initialize memory in heap by using 'new' operator.
Hope this can help you:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>

struct str {
int x;
int y;
int z;
};

int main()
{
  int N;
  std::cin>>N;
  str  **Array1 = new str*[N]; //N can be up to 200
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    Array1[i] = new str[N];
  }
  // set value
  for (int row = 0; row < N; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < N; ++col) {
        Array1[row][col].x=10;
        Array1[row][col].y=10;
        Array1[row][col].z=10;
    }
  }
  // get value
  for (int row = 0; row < N; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < N; ++col) {
        std::cout << Array1[row][col].x << std::endl;
        std::cout << Array1[row][col].y << std::endl;
        std::cout << Array1[row][col].z << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When wanting to allocate a 2D array in C++ using the `new` operator, you must declare a `(*pointer-to-array)[N]` and then allocate with `new type [N][N];`

For example, you can declare and allocate for your `Array1` as follows:

```
#define N 200

struct str {
    int x, y, z;
};

int main (void) {

    str (*Array1)[N] = new str[N][N];  /* allocate */

    /* use Array1 as 2D array */

    delete [] Array1;                  /* free memory */
}
```

However, ideally, you would want to let the C++ containers library type `vector` handle the memory management for your. For instance you can:

```
#include<vector>
..
std::vector <std::vector <str>> Array1;
```

Then to fill `Array1`, fill a temporary `std::vector<str> tmp;` for each row (1D array) of `str` and then `Array1.push_back(tmp);` to add the filled `tmp` vector to your `Array1`. Your access can still be 2D indexing (e.g. `Array1[a][b].x, Array1[a][b].y, ...`, but you benefit from auto-memory management provided by the container. Much more robust and less error prone than handling the memory yourself.